# Syntax error with single quotes in Laravel 5 Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I've been trying to write a massive `update` query with a `where` clause, and I've found that Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Query Builder makes a syntax error.

The query is the following:

```
$query = $this->model
    ->where('state', "pending")
    ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR')
    ->update(['state' => "timeout"]);
```

Which is translated to this:

```
update `orders`
set `state` = timeout, `updated_at` = 2016-09-21 21:47:39
where `state` = pending and created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
```

This query keeps failing since the values for the columns `state` and `updated_at` are not written with single quotes.

How can I force Laravel to write to put the single quotes correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `where('created_at', DB::raw('NOW() - ..'));`

And why are you putting peding in single quotes? Laravel escapes values automatically.

Comment: I knew that I can use DB::raw, but I'd like to find a more... elegant solution, sort to speak. I'm using double quotes because the query builder is removing them too if I use single ones... Maybe this is related to the main problem? (Btw `state` is an enum)

Comment: Enum should not make a difference, because a string is sent to mysql anyway. I thinks that DB::raw would be a more elegant solution. If you start hacking like this, then I suggest just writing a raw query.

Comment: I'd rather use the Query Builder tools. I've edited the question to include the single quotes problem in the `state` column, I think they might be related

Comment: Ok, nevermind, this works, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis why not to use `where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addHours(-12))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
$results  = MyModel::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('created_at','>=',\DB::raw('"'.$from.'"'))
            ->where('created_at','<=',\DB::raw('"'.$to.'"'))
            ->orderby('id','desc')
            ->paginate(15);
```

Hope this helps.